# How to bring Inline from a RichTextBox Child into View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, focus, richtextbox

How can i focus a `Inline` in a `RichTextBox`?
I Create a `FlowDocument` from a Text-File and load it in my `richTextBox1`
and mark one `Inline` after an other accordingly to a Button_click (be recreating the `FlowDocument`)

### with this code:

```
            richTextBox1.SelectAll();
            richTextBox1.Selection.Text = "";

            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
            int iZeile = 0;

            string[] split = text.Split(new string[] {"\r\n"},StringSplitOptions.None);

                    foreach (string s in split)
                    {
                        if (iZeile != 27)
                        {
                            paragraph.Inlines.Add(s + "\r\n"); // adds line added without marking
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Run run = new Run(split[27]); // adds line with marking
                            run.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
                            paragraph.Inlines.Add(run);
                            paragraph.Inlines.Add("\r\n");
                        }
                        iZeile++;
                    }

            FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);
            richTextBox1.Document = new FlowDocument();
            richTextBox1.Document = document;
            Keyboard.Focus(richTextBox1);
        }
```

I know its not.. perfect.

### the Issue

It works so far but the problem that occurs is me Market `Inline` doesn't comes intoView. Is there a easy way to bring this `Inline` intoView?

Comment: Wat too much code for this question. Please summarize.

Comment: i want to show the marked line so that i dont have to scroll, if the flowdocument is tho long @Henk Holterman

Comment: No reason to post _all_ the case blocks.

Comment: I summarized it, now I hope you can read it better @HenkHolterman

Comment: Did you experiment with FrameworkContentElement.BringIntoView() ? But it might not work because you build up 1 gigantic paragraph.

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The straightforward solution seemed to be `FrameworkContentElement.BringIntoView()` but after putting it in the code below it initially had no effect. As it turns out this is one of these timing issues (I've seen similar problems in WinForms) that can be solved by processing the outstanding Windows Messages. WPF has no direct equivalent of `DoEvents()` but there exists a well known substitute.

I placed this in a ButtonClick, changes marked with `//**`:

```
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        Inline selected = null;   //**

        richTextBox1.SelectAll();
        richTextBox1.Selection.Text = "";

        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"..\..\MainWindow.xaml.cs");
        int iZeile = 0;

        string[] split = text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach (string s in split)
        {
            if (iZeile != 27)
            {
                paragraph.Inlines.Add(s + "\r\n"); // adds line added without marking
            }
            else
            {
                Run run = new Run(split[27]); // adds line with marking
                run.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
                paragraph.Inlines.Add(run);
                paragraph.Inlines.Add("\r\n");
                selected = run;                // ** remember this element
            }
            iZeile++;
        }

        FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);
        richTextBox1.Document = new FlowDocument();
        richTextBox1.Document = document;
        Keyboard.Focus(richTextBox1);

        DoEvents();                   // ** this is required, probably a bug
        selected.BringIntoView();     // **
```

And the helper method, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502200/60761):

```
    public static void DoEvents()
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, 
            new Action(delegate { }));
    }
```

Comment: I had the same problem with BringIntoView().  For some reason, using tactics from the second answer works without DoEvents() and BringIntoView().  Replace them with code like this:
`Rect rctStart = selected.ContentStart.GetCharacterRect(System.Windows.Documents.LogicalDirection.Forward);
    Rect rctEnd = selected.ContentEnd.GetCharacterRect(System.Windows.Documents.LogicalDirection.Forward);
    richTextBox1.ScrollToVerticalOffset((rctStart.Top + rctEnd.Bottom
        - richTextBox1.ViewportHeight) / 2 + richTextBox1.VerticalOffset);`

Answer (score 3):

you should try one of this methods

```
richTextBox.SelectionStart = richTextBox.Text.Length;
richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
```

.

```
richTextBox.AppendText(text);  
richTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
```

futher informations are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.scrolltocaret.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.scrolltoend.aspx)

**Edit**

ok after a bit of digging in the WPF RichTextBox i thing you cloud try `richTextBox.ScrollToVerticalOffset(Offset)`
to get the Offset maybe you could use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2577699/1993545)

### EDIT 2

ok after some more research i found following [Link](http://shevaspace.blogspot.de/2007/11/how-to-search-text-in-wpf-flowdocument.html) where you can download **[this](http://www.cnblogs.com/Files/sheva/SearchInFlowDocumentDemo.zip)** working  example

Comment: the first method is in windows forms useful. The second let me scroll to the end of the richtextbox and not to the, which i have add

Comment: to calculate the Offset see the following [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3487361/1993545)