# wpf richtextbox BringIntoView Not working using TextRange.ClearAllProperties?

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, richtextbox

i am programming in wpf.i have to scroll one page up when highlighted word move from viewportHeight.So i am using the below code.it works fine.

```
FrameworkContentElement fce = (textRange.Start.Parent as FrameworkContentElement);
            if (fce != null)
            {
                fce.BringIntoView();
            }
```

But after i need to use the below code for highlight word.

```
   TextRange fullRange = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
                fullRange.ClearAllProperties(); 
                TextPointer start = fullRange.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(offset);
                TextPointer end = start.GetPositionAtOffset(length);
                TextRange textRange = rtb.Selection;
                textRange.Select(start, end);
textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(m_DehighlightbackgroundColor));
textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(m_DehighlightforegroundColor));
```

After i used `fullRange.ClearAllProperties();` the `fce.BringIntoView();` not working.I mean not scroll to highlighted word.

So,how to solve this issue?

Regards
Arjun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer solved a similar issue for me:

[How to bring Inline from a RichTextBox Child into View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411725/how-to-bring-inline-from-a-)
richtextbox-child-into-view

To summarise, try putting the following before BringIntoView:

`Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(delegate { }));`